# Query String attached to all my pages on my website rediects to a white screen

Tags: redirect, query-string

I have been having this problem for over 6 months and no one seems to know how to fix this.  Even my hosting provider can't figure it out.

Whenever I post a link from any of the pages I have on my website onto any social media platform or send an email to my students on Udemy (e learning platform that sells courses) they add a query string (the question mark after the forward slash of my doamain/pages).

The problem is because these sites are adding query strings to the end of links form my website, the pages redirect to a blank white screen.

When you remove the query string, my pages are fine.  This is happening on all of my domains which are hosted on HostGator.  They have been no help and don't even know how to fix this problem.

Please help!

I downloaded a plugin that should be able to remove query strings but has not helped either.